# How to use the Async pipe beyond presentational stuff?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am having a hard time understanding the Async pipe and its use outside of just being presentational.
I understand the advantages of it in combination with OnPush. But what if i want to change the data that i get from the Observable?

Consider the following example:

**Angular Service that loads marbles from the server**

```
export class DecisionServiceService {
    constructor(private http: HttpService) { }

    getMarbles() {
        return this.http.getMarbles();
    }
}
```

**Angular Component that shows marbles, but also deletes or adds marbles**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'marbles',
    template: `<ng-container *ngIf="marbles$ | async as marbles">
    <div class="marbles" *ngFor="let marble of marbles">
        {{marble.name}}
    </div>
    <button (click)="deleteMarble()">delete marble</button>
    <button (click)="addMarble()">add marble</button>
</ng-container>`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MarblesComponent implements OnInit {
    public marbles$: Observable<Marble[]>;


    constructor(private marblesService: MarblesService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.marbles$ = this.marblesService.getMarbles();
    }

    deleteMarble() {
        // 
    }
    addMarble() {
        // ???
    }
    
}
```

In this case, how would i delete or add marbles? In other words: How can i adjust the data that i get from an Observable if I use the async pipe.

Comment: Too many questions in one post. To answer one question *what if i want to change the data that i get from the Observable* ...use the pipeable map rxjs operator `somestream$.pipe(map(transformDataFunction))`

Comment: You don't use `| async` beyond presentational stuff. As above you can use RxJS operators to apply transformations to the data from the source observable, but given the use of an `HttpService` in your example I'd guess how to actually add and remove marbles is a POST and DELETE. You could separate the exposed marbles from the service to a subject that gets updated on those actions, rather than directly returning the GET's result, see e.g. https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html.

Answer (score 1):

your `MarblesService` should have the methods `addMarble()`, `deleteMarble()`. And in the component, calling `addMarble` should invoke this service method, like so:

```
   addMarble() {
        this.marbleService.addMarble();
    }
```

- In this way, you will have to add a `marbleId` parameter to these methods.

Once the service updates its `marbles[]` state, the `marbles$` observable will emit a new value, and your view will update accordingly.

Another benefit of the `async` pipe is that it unsubscribes automatically, so you don't have to care about memory leaks from this observable.

Comment: No - the `marbles$` observable will **not** emit a new value, since it comes from an http request, which emits a single value then completes. `marbles$` would have to observe `addMarble` and `deleteMarble` and [forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to `getMarbles` to emit a new value.

Comment: BTW I meant [switchmap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) not forkjoin. Still drinking my morning coffee.